# Couln't complete a android layout task

Tags: android, date

I was learning to make android apps via Udacity and was stuck in a question. In his [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XWBQLPMq08M&list=PLqzrDrMjiT3TIXKXlw8RpBbF-WVzVBao7&index=15) I was told to make a layout using drag and drop features of Android studio. As I was working, I couldn't find any option to insert the today's date. Should I simply use a plain text field? [the layout scrren](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyPoX.png)

Comment: If you just want to display it, use a simple TextView. If the user should be able to edit it, use a TextField or a DatePicker / TimePicker.
Have look at the different UI elements and learn their differences.
Keep in mind that you always have to manually supply their value (in your case the today's date).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my Android Studio on the Design tab of the xml, it shows Date under the Text Field category but you can switch to the Text view and create it in there as well, check out [this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html) to understand and [this page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType) for all your options. In your case, I would try adding `android:inputType="date"` to the xml in the field you want to be a date. Hope this helps.